# How to make the cells inside of a tableview begin lower down?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

I have a tableview. Right now the first cell will begin right at the top of the tableview, but I want it to start some number below the top of the tableview so that I can `addSubview()` in that spot without covering content in the first cell.

Below you can see what I want to achieve.

*The rectangle in the center represents the cells, the line at the top represents the top most of the tableview.*

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: You don't. The contents of a table view belong to the table view. You should not try to add subviews to a table view.

As @rickramirr says, you either need to position your table view lower on the screen, or use a header view that contains the contents you want.

(If you decide to position your table view lower down, need to either not manage your table view with a `UITableViewController`, or have a `UITableViewController` as a child view controller of the screen's main view controller. A `UITableViewController` is kind of dumb, and only knows how to manage a table view and nothing else.)

Comment: how can I disable the header's stick-to-top feature?

Comment: What do you mean? You want the header to scroll out of view as the cells scroll? You would need to make it a section header, or create a custom table view where the first cell is a custom type that contains the view(s) you want.

Comment: This did the trick: contentTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(), style: .grouped)

Answer (score 0):

I think that maybe you should add a custom header to your table view or put another view above your table view. Here is Apple docs to customize your header: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/table_views/adding_headers_and_footers_to_table_sections

Comment: I update my answer to include apple docs for header customization.

Answer (score 0):

All the views that you want to insert between one tableView cell and another must extend UITableViewCells too. You can create custom cells by defining a new xib file containing a UITableViewCell, whose content could be whatever view you want. Then, you must create a swift file that extends UITableViewCell associated with the xib file. Finally you need to record that cell into the table, either programmatically or by manually inserting it into the storyboard within the table. At that point you will decide its position using the UITableViewDelegate "cellForRowAt" method.